# HTML Helper for page link creation - trying to understand

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

Below is the complete source for my HTML helper file (PageHelper.cs) and it works perfectly.  I am learning ASP.NET MVC 3 and using the 'Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 Framework' book by aPress.  I love the flow of the book and am learning a lot, however every now and then it provides working code without a real explanation as to why it works and this is one of these examples.  I've spent a considerable amount of time with Google and Stack on this one. To get to the point now...

I am hoping someone can explain the flow of what is happening within the 'public static MvcHtmlString PageLinks'.  I'm trying to learn this and not simply follow along in the book (NOTE:  The excessive comments in the code are my own - meant to reinforce learning).

My take on it is **MvcHtmlString** is used to tell the browser not to reencode the HTML again because the resulting HTML already is.  **this** is used to capture the page the user is currently on.  **html** is the instantiation of the **HtmlHelper** class? (although **html** is never mentioned again - why is that?).  **pagingInfo** is the instantiation of my **PagingInfo** class that holds properties used in the HTML creation that gets returned.  Here is the part I can't wrap my head around at all....the **Func** part.  The book explains that the **Func** parameters provide the ability to pass in a delegate that will be used to generate the links to view other pages - not sure what this means and why the function route is needed at all.

The rest of the code I can follow along.  Sorry for the long winded post, but I'm seeking clarity.  If any of my code comments or explanations are incorrect, please correct me.  Thanks in advance!

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using SportsStore.WebUI.Models;

//You use HTML helpers in a view to render HTML content. An HTML helper, in most 
//cases, is just a method that returns a string.  You can build an entire ASP.NET
//MVC application without using a single HTML helper. However, HTML helpers make 
//your life as a developer easier. By taking advantage of helpers, you can build
//your views with far less work.  Write once, reuse often.  

//We use 'MvcHtmlString' so that the result doesn't get re-encoded in the view. 
//It is part of the MVC framework and when you create your own HTML helper
//methods like this one, always use it.

namespace SportsStore.WebUI.HtmlHelpers
{
    //This is public so it can be accessed in other areas, however the 'static'
    //means it can't be instantiated.
    public static class PagingHelpers
    {
        //This is an HTML Helper method that we call 'PageLinks', which generates
        //HTML for a set of page links using the info provided in a PagingInfo
        //object.  Remember that extension methods are only available for use
        //when the namespace that contains it is in scope.  In a code file, this
        //is done with a 'using' statement, but for a Razor view, we must add a 
        //configuration entry to the View-specific Web.config file OR add a
        //'@using' statement to the view itself.  For this project we chose to 
        //use the Web.config file to keep the View less cluttered.

        public static MvcHtmlString PageLinks(this HtmlHelper html,
                                              PagingInfo pagingInfo,
                                              Func<int, string> pageUrl)
        {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 1; i <= pagingInfo.TotalPages; i++)
            {
                TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("a"); //Construct an <a> tag
                tag.MergeAttribute("href", pageUrl(i));
                tag.InnerHtml = i.ToString();
                if (i == pagingInfo.CurrentPage)
                    tag.AddCssClass("selected");
                result.Append(tag.ToString());
            }**

            return MvcHtmlString.Create(result.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are built-in HTML Helpers and in this chapter, the author created a customized `PageLinks()` HTML helper for pagination. As you can see, the helper class returns a string for building HTML `<a>` tag link. This static helper class is used by `PagingInfo` model.

Each time a user clicks the page number, it is passed to `PagingInfo` as `currentPage` parameter value. The author then instantiates a `PagingInfo` object in the `view model class ProductListViewModel` whenever a view (ex. `List.cshtml`) is modeled upon this view model.

On the view, call the `@Html.PageLinks` to show the `<a>` tag link built by the `PageLinks` helper method.

I hope this helps. If you wish to learn more about the HTML helpers extension methods, read

> Chapter 2 under "Creating a simple Data-Entry application"

and

> Chapter 19 for "Customized HTML Helper"

Answer (score 0):

I was just writing this code from the same book while learning MVC 3 so I stumbled upon your question on the web.

You need to understand what [EXTENSION METHODS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) are:

That's why you need "**this**", it is a rule that says when you extend a class with a new method first parameter is always **a class type** of the class you would like to extend, preceded by "this".

So, in our great book we have **this HtmlHelper html** (this - class type - class reference)

Hope I helped you, if not ask what you don't get.